# C++ macro inside macro

Tags: c++, macros

I'm trying to do something along the lines of this:

```
#define DEF(name) \
#ifndef DEFINED_##name \
    MyClass name; \
#endif
```

However, I get the following error:

```
include/file.h:38:17: error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
 #define DEF(name) \
```

Is there anyways to do this?